# How to read in parameters to R script from commandline when doing GNU parallel jobs on HPC

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gnu, hpc

I am very new to GNU parallel, and I have some very basic questions. I need to do a large parameter sweep, and I have 6 different parameters. Following the documentation provided by the HPC cluster I am using, my command for submitting GNU jobs is the following:

`parallel -j 2 --colsep '\t' R CMD BATCH Rscript.R --a {1} --b {2} --c {3} --d {4} --e {5} --f {6} :::: parameter.txt`

parameter.txt contains the tab separated values of the 6 parameters (a-f). Say `a=1, b=2, ..., f=6`. After googling, I imagined that the Rscript will read in the parameters by `commandArgs()`. But this appearantly does not work. Simply setting Rscript.R to be a single line:

`args<-commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)`

the results for `args` is `NULL`. What is the correct way of reading in the parameters into Rscript.R in this case? Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest you use `RScript` rather than `R CMD BATCH` to run your script. It makes it easier to pass command line args. Otherwise you need to use `--args`. Where is this "::::" syntax documented?

Comment: @MrFlick Hi, I just tried RScript, it is the same. The documents I am referring to is https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/GNU_Parallel#Arguments_List

Comment: What exactly did your `Rscript` command look like? How are you capturing the output?

Comment: Actually, never mind. There was some delay in the output. It is working now! Thanks a lot!